# Ivermectin Paper with Hard To Believe Conclusion, Can I Get Some Help?

Tags: covid-19

Is this a robust study and are the conclusions supported by the data?

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8417612/

Emphasis is mine.

> Two doses (300 μg/kg/dose in a gap of 72 hours) of ivermectin
> chemoprophylaxis reduced COVID-19 infection by 83% among HCWs for one
> month. **Ivermectin is a safe and effective strategy to prevent
> COVID-19, in the containment of pandemic alongside vaccine.** Further
> research is required to guide the frequency of chemoprevention,
> acceptability, and cost-effectiveness in the community setting.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on [skeptics.se]? Either way, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance about our ways as and when. Welcome to the network.

Comment: Think about aspects of a clinical trial that should be there (but aren't in this paper) to show some effect. Also check out the Kaplan-Meyer plot (2'nd to last fig?)...interesting. Also, ivermectin _does_ work in the lab, just at concs well above what you can achieve in the body.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on skeptics and is crossposted there.